# Prevent user from submitting login form before Javascript is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, forms, server-side-rendering

tWe have a login form in React App. We use Server Side Rendering. Some users are able to submit the form before the JavaScript is loaded. The result is a failed login attempt for the user and a log message of the default form GET request which contains the users login credentials. Both is bad.

This is our generated form:

```
<form>
    <input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="user" id="user" name="user" type="text" aria-label="Benutzername"
        value="">
    <input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="current-password" id="password" name="password" type="password"
        aria-label="Passwort" value="">
    <button tabindex="0" type="submit" data-e2e="einloggen-button" aria-disabled="false">Einloggen</button>
</form>
```

I thought that might be a common problem with Server Side Rendering. Is there a solution where the user can't send the form and we can still have valid HTML?

Comment: Remove the `form` element? (Input fields don’t _need_ to be inside a form, in terms of HTML validity. Not sure what effects that might have in regard to storing passwords in the browser though.) Or, make the fields `disabled` in the HTML, and have the JS remove that attribute when it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable submit before document load, you can use this code in your 
  head tag.

```
 <script>
    document.forms[0].querySelector('button').disabled = true;
    document.onload = () => {
         document.forms[0].querySelector('button').disabled = false;
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use pointer-events: none during the DOM loading, and disable it when the page is fully loaded:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  const body = document.querySelector("body");
  if (document.readyState === "loading") {
    console.log("Page is loading"); // Not running
  } else if (document.readyState === "interactive") {
    console.log("DOM is Loaded");
    body.style = 'pointer-events: none;' // Button disabled on click
  } else {
    console.log("Page is loaded");
    // body.style = 'pointer-events: auto;'
  }
};
```

Here you can find live example on [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/DisastrousWeeklySort)

You can also just add ***required*** field on the HTML, that will avoid your users to submit an empty form.